# Error message while trying to set state in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react app and everything works fine up till the point i try to setState in the code below.

The error message I got is written below:

> "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
>     (found: object with keys {invoiceId, branchId, customerId, 
>     routeNumber, settledDate, orderNumber}). If you meant to render a 
>     collection of children, use an array instead."

I am not able to setState to queryResult. What is wrong with this code?

```
            constructor(){
                super();
                this.state = {     
                  queryResult:[]
            };

            searchForInvoicesByDates(startDate, endDate){

                let dataToWorkWith = [];
                dataToWorkWith = this.cleanUpInvoicesByDate();

                  //format startdate and enddate
                  let cleanedStartDate =  moment(startDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                  let cleanedEndDate =   moment(endDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

                  let filteredResult = [];

                  for(let i = 0; i < dataToWorkWith.length; i++){      
                    if(dataToWorkWith[i].settledDate >= cleanedStartDate &&  dataToWorkWith[i].settledDate <= cleanedEndDate) {
                      filteredResult.push(dataToWorkWith[i]);
                    }
                  }

                  this.setState({queryResult:filteredResult}); //problem is here
            }
```

Comment: first - you forgot to close defining of the state in constructor, second - show your render function

Comment: Please include `render` in your question, the problem possibly is an Object being returned as a JSX element, which is not a valid operation.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be due to rendering of *queryResult* directly in render function. Try to use map on *queryResult* in render function like this:

```
render(){
  return queryResult.map(query => <div> query </div>)
}
```